# Testing paypal with rails URL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have paypal in my rails app and I want to test it, the request looks fine but for some reason when submitting the url has attached localhost:3000 and gives me this error. I am calling the adress in a secrets.yml file

> [2015-01-20 14:33:31] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept
>    registry part: localhost:3000api.sandbox.paypal.com (or bad hostname?)
>           C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1202:in `rescue in merge'
>           C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1199:in`merge'
>           C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:220:in `setup_header'
>           C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:150:in`send_response'
>           C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in `run'
>           C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`block in start_thread
>   '

code looks like this

```
 def paypal_url(return_path)
    values = {
        business: "username-facilitator@yahoo.com",
        cmd: "_xclick",
        upload: 1,
        return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
        invoice: id,
        amount: course.price,
        item_name: course.name,
        item_number: course.id,
        quantity: '1',
        notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
    }
    "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated Paypal URL is wrong:

```
localhost:3000api.sandbox.paypal.com
```

Modify the `Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host` to `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com`